# How to replace a date in filename with current date in Groovy Script

Tags: javascript, java, groovy

Here is the sample input and out put files and filename is not a constant length and will comes in different length, can you help me someone to done in groovy/java
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmFFM.png

Comment: here the file name is not constant , the file name will come dynamically with date

Answer (score 1):

You have a constant length date in filename and it.s located just before file extension.

Use regexp.

```
def today = new Date().format('yyyyMMdd')
def newName = "aaa_bbb_20201222.txt".replaceAll( /\d{6}(\.\w+)$/ , today+'$1' )
```

Regexp explained: https://regex101.com/r/Q5uDtS/1